# Android Help with downloading an APK from within an app without going through the browser

Tags: android, file, uri, apk

Hope someone can help me on this,

I would like to download an APK from within an app i have, but without going through the browser via a uri.

I can do it with a video file like so

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    //Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);
```

But cannot find a way to do it with a .apk file, so a new app.apk with start to install.

Hope someone can help
thanks
Lucy X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the same technique as you are using for the video. However, you have to specify the APK MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`).

**UPDATE**

For example:

```
Intent thingyToInstall=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

thingyToInstall.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://here/is/the/path/to/the.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(thingyToInstall);
```

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thanks for the info, could you show me how to code it with a URL which is differnet from the above. Many Thanks ---------

I have this but would like to add the Mime Type as you suggest

----------------        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://domain.com/android/direct/apk/app.apk"));
   startActivity(browserIntent);  -------------- Sorry hows it laid out, but the enter key will not allow spacing......

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, but i'am receiving an error on "SetDataAndType" any ideas what could be wrong, thanks again.. Lucy

Comment: @Lucy: Sorry, failed to parse the URL into a `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks...Unfortunately it produces a force close on a button click, any resolution to this happening? Updated the code above to match what i have, Thankyou, Lucy

Comment: @Lucy: You are going to have to debug from there.

Comment: @CommonWare: Dont have much of a clue, but could it be that Intent.ACTION_VIEW needs to be different. ----------- Dam, thought i was almost there ----------- Error Bug below ------------ Cant find anywhere to put it as not enough chars...